# Copy vector in Octave without first element

Tags: octave

I need to copy vector without the first element in Octave. How do I do this?
Tried

```
    newTheta = theta([2,length(theta)],:)
```

But then newTheta is only `[0;0]`

Thanks,
Kakoli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `end` keyword can be used for indexing:

```
vslice = v(2:end)
```

You can slice rows and/or columns as well:

```
rowslice = m(2:end,:)
colslice = m(:,2:end)
```

Please do not use `length` in this case.

Comment: out of curiosity, why not use length? I've never liked how `end` is used both to represent the end of a vector and the end of a loop

Comment: @user3288829 then don't use `end` to end a loop, use `endfor`. Using `end` in this situation makes it a lot more readable, the Octave parser knows the difference, and it prevents future bugs because length can change between number of rows and columns depending on the size.

Answer (score 0):

```
octave:1> theta = linspace(0,pi,6)
theta =

   0.00000   0.62832   1.25664   1.88496   2.51327   3.14159

octave:2> newTheta = theta(2:length(theta))
newTheta =

   0.62832   1.25664   1.88496   2.51327   3.14159
```

In this case, `:` is the actual operator. It's called slicing in python but I don't know what they call it in octave.

What you wrote actually returned the second and last rows of theta, which I'm guessing was a column vector with zeros in the second and last place.

```
octave:7> b = [1; 0; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 0]
b =

   1
   0
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   0

octave:8> b([2,length(b)],:)
ans =

   0
   0
```